# what json structure does simple oauth expect?

Tags: authentication-authorization

Drupal 8. 
I'm new with simple Oauth. 
I had manage to do this: 
[image]

But I want to do it with the Raw format, cuz my frontend is in Angular, so I will send a Json to Drupal.

This is my first try:

```
{
    "grant_type":"password", 
    "client_id":"f011cc58-40ce-43a9-8f71-842494e3a997", 
    "client_secret":"abc123", 
    "username":"test", 
    "password":"test"
}
```

And this is the response:

> {
>       "error": "invalid_grant",
>       "message": "The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid,
>   expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the
>   authorization request, or was issued to another client.",
>       "hint": "Check the configuration to see if the grant is enabled." }

I have set up the Content-type: Application/json but I got the same result.

Any idea??

[image]

Comment: Not a structure issue, the error says something to do with your Refresh Token `refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked...` So you need a new one, I hope this helps [Refresh Token Grant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9BSwL2frROY&index=5&list=PLZOQ_ZMpYrZtqy5-o7KoDhM3n6M0duBjX)

Comment: @NoSssweat But I am working just with the `client_id` It doesn´t expire. And... the other reason for the error, is the authorization grant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend if the backend can receive a JSON format.

In my case, I am working with the Drupal 8 Module simple Oauth. and the The format for OAuth 2.0 Bearer tokens is actually described in a separate spec, [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750).

More concrete [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#page-4)

> The entity-body follows the encoding requirements of the
> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" content-type as defined by HTML
> 4.01 [W3C.REC-html401-19991224].

So, In my particular case, I will try to send a form-data from angular.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify your data.
To do this install npm package qs, then create object

```
const data = {
    "grant_type":"password", 
    "client_id":"f011cc58-40ce-43a9-8f71-842494e3a997", 
    "client_secret":"abc123", 
    "username":"test", 
    "password":"test"
}
```

And use in request

```
axios.post('oauth/token', qs.stringify(data))
```